# Linking first name and gender in Faker library

Tags: python, faker

I am seeking to generate a fake dataset for my research using the Faker library. I am unable to link gender and first name of the person.  Can I expect some help in this regard?  The function is given below.

```
def faker_categorical(num=1, seed=None):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    fake.seed_instance(seed)
    
    output = [
        {
            "gender": np.random.choice(["M", "F"], p=[0.5, 0.5]),
            "GivenName": fake.first_name_male() if "gender"=="M" else fake.first_name_female(),
            "Surname": fake.last_name(),
            "Zipcode": fake.zipcode(),
            "Date of Birth": fake.date_of_birth(),
            "country": np.random.choice(["United Kingdom", "France", "Belgium"]),
        }
        for x in range(num)
    ]
    return output

df = pd.DataFrame(faker_categorical(num=1000))
```

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is often an awful way to explain what you do want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I guess what you are looking for is a way to refer to the result from `np.random.choice()` from two different places in your code.  Easy -- assign it to a temporary variable, then refer to that variable from both places.

```py
def faker_categorical(num=1, seed=None):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    fake.seed_instance(seed)
    
    output = []
    for x in range(num):
      gender = np.random.choice(["M", "F"], p=[0.5, 0.5])
      output.append(
        {
            "gender": gender,
            "GivenName": fake.first_name_male() if gender=="M" else fake.first_name_female(),
            "Surname": fake.last_name(),
            "Zipcode": fake.zipcode(),
            "Date of Birth": fake.date_of_birth(),
            "country": np.random.choice(["United Kingdom", "France", "Belgium"]),
        })
    return output
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I admit my poor effort.  Please accept my apologies for the shoddy explanation.

Comment: This solution may produce "m" for female names and vise versa

Comment: @VictorShytiuk Why do you say that? The code specifically takes care to pick male names when the gender lottery produced `"M"`, and female otherwise.

Comment: (It doesn't try to link names to cultures, so you could get uncharacteristically many Brians and Sheilas from Belgium, and Marie-Pierres and Claudine-Yvettes from Yorkshire.)

Comment: ("Zip code" is a US concept; similarly, you would want the postal codes to be valid for the country you picked, too. I believe France generally has five digits, Beligium four, and the UK system requires a dual PhD from Hogwarts and Mordor to even try to explain.)

Comment: (For bonus points, you want Flemish first names mostly from the correct regions in Belgium, with some bleeding, and some leakage in both directions with the Walloon ones, with a sprinkling of German, and an unholy mix in Brussels with some international flair.)

Comment: @tripleee I think `fake.last_name()` knows nothing about what `"gender": gender` returns, isn't it?

Comment: @VictorShytiuk Last names don't have any gender information in many cultures. Obviously the code for first names could be adapted if you have a fake name generator for such last names, but it seems the OP doesn't.

Comment: (For the record, e.g. some Slavic names have genders, so e.g. Mr. Antonov's sister would be Ms. Antonova.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a piece of research in classification linking a name to a Gender,for example John is 99.8% male,and Maria is 99.8% female. You can read it [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Gender+by+Name) and can also download a `.csv` file which maps different names to genders. What I did when I needed fake data about people was parse the dataset and if the value was there I assigned the classified gender,if it wasn't (Because of locals or something else) I just assigned a `np.random.choice(["MALE", "FEMALE"])`. Hope this helped